# Helper method to extract a specific string from long message

Tags: c#, strings, complexity

```
private string ExtractExceptionMesssage(string exceptionMessage)
{
    const string startWord = "Message&gt";
    int startWordLength = startWord.Length;
    const string endWord = "/Message&gt";
    var length = exceptionMessage.Length;
    int index = 0;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (index < length)
    {
        var startIndex = exceptionMessage.IndexOf(startWord, index, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (startIndex < 0)
            break;
        var endIndex = exceptionMessage.IndexOf(endWord, startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (endIndex < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        var len = endIndex - 4 - (startIndex + startWord.Length); // -4 is ".&lt"
        sb.AppendLine(exceptionMessage.Substring(startIndex + startWordLength, len));
        index = endIndex + endWord.Length + 1;
    }

    if (sb.Length == 0) sb.Append("Unknown error");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'll appreciate any idea of how to make it better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consistent style**
You kind of mixing your styles with curly braces - your indentation is inconsistent, and for two duplicate `if`s with single statement you once omit the braces, and on the other not. Choose a style, and stick to it - it will make your code more readable

**Magic numbers**
You made a curious choice to omit the `"&lt;"` from you start and end indicators, which made you add the mysterious `- 4` to your `len` calculation. This is a major maintenance issue, since tomorrow you will want to extract with unescaped text, where the `"&lt;"` will be reduced to `"<"`, and your code will stop working...

**Use the powers of the tools at hand**
Your solution could be much simpler if you used [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to solve it:

```
private string ExtractExceptionMesssage(string exceptionMessage) {
    string pattern = @"&lt;Message&gt;(.+?)lt;/Message&gt;";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
    if (matches.Count > 0) {
       foreach (Match match in matches) {
         sb.AppendLine(match.Value);
       }
    } else {
       return "Unknown error";
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like XML in XML (that's why there are `&gt;`s instead of `>`s). When working with XML, you should use a XML parsing library, like LINQ to XML, instead of trying parse it manually.

Assuming you can use LINQ to XML to get the XML unencoded (with `>`s) and that it's actually valid XML (with a single root element), then you can use something like:

```
private string ExtractExceptionMesssage(string exceptionMessage)
{
    var doc = XElement.Parse(exceptionMessage);
    return string.Join("\n", doc.Descendants("Message").Select(m => m.Value));
}
```